# Issue with Query function giving NO_COLUMN: Col3 error

Tags: google-sheets, formula

So i'm not sure what the issue is as the original Formula was

> =QUERY({'All Report Sheet'!$A$1:A,'All Report Sheet'!$B$1:$B},"select count(Col1) where (Col1 matches '"&JOIN("|",{$K$2:$K$4})&"') and Col2='"&$A2&"' label count(Col1) ''")

The Above worked perfectly

And i made a slight adjustment to accommodate an extra column so changed to

> =QUERY({'All Report Sheet'!$B$2:B,'All Report Sheet'!$C$2:$C},"select count(Col2) where (Col2 matches '"&JOIN("|",{$S$2:$S$4})&"') and Col3='"&$A2&"' label count(Col2) ''")

I'm Receiving NO_Column: Col3 but there is a Column 3 on the All report sheet so i'm unsure what the issue is?

Comment: `{'All Report Sheet'!$B$2:B,'All Report Sheet'!$C$2:$C}` in this part there are only two columns.

Comment: Okay so i'm an idiot, it is not returning an Error now but it also not returning Values so coming back as 0 it doesn't seem to be Counting, Also getting errors where Names in '"&$A2&" Contain an ' Example O'Neil - Unable to parse query string for Function QUERY parameter 2: PARSE_ERROR: Encountered " <ID> "Laire "" at line 1

Comment: Can you share a sample workbook so that we can check.

Comment: I cant unfortunately due to Sensitive Data, B:B is a list of Engagements that come through on a variable sized report, C:C is the caseworker on that report, S2:S4 is a list of engagements that go under 1 group, and A2 is a cell with a caseworker name in it, The formula worked on my smaller sheet the first one, but the 2nd code i used for the larger one seems to not count correctly

Comment: You can put few dummy data to a sample file. No need to share actual sheet.

Comment: I've just updated the dummy sheet and it is working on that sheet but not for all Names https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nEeulAtoiHS810VyafJCu07EyvN6xIHjdaQo46Wb5ys/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({IFNA(VLOOKUP('All Report'!B1:B, {
 "Group TestA",  "Company Group 1";  "Group TestB",  "Company Group 1"; 
 "Group Test C", "Company Group 1";  "GroupTestD",   "Company Group 2"; 
 "GroupTestE",   "Company Group 2";  "GroupTestF",   "Company Group 2"}, 2, 0), 
 'All Report'!B1:B), 'All Report'!C1:C},
 "select Col2,count(Col2) where Col2 is not null group by Col2 pivot Col1", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah so i was thinking about doing them separately, but the Original sheet i need the formula for only needs Group Test A,B and C and Group Test D,E and F to be grouped, also needed it to be easily scaled as Grouping 1 will consist of 70+ Engagement names, i'm not sure but i think it may have something to do with the engagement names itself as an Example one would be close to "Client - [XX] Client Engagement" i'm not sure if the original code is having issues with that, when i added spaces to the dummy sheet some of the names on the first Tab stopped returning Values

Comment: So this would work, it is just a case of it being a little impracticable to scale to 70+ Engagements under 1 group

Comment: @KGRsL `{
 "Group TestA",  "Company Group 1";  "Group TestB",  "Company Group 1"; 
 "Group Test C", "Company Group 1";  "GroupTestD",   "Company Group 2"; 
 "GroupTestE",   "Company Group 2";  "GroupTestF",   "Company Group 2"}` this can be replaced by a range

Comment: Sorry i dont think i fully understand what's going on here